# Exchange deposits using smart contracts and externally owned accounts

Tags: contract-development, transactions, tokens, ether

While researching how different exchanges handle user deposits, I noticed a stark contrast between several prominent exchanges.

**Kraken:**

> [Exchanges like Kraken](https://steemit.com/cryptocurrency/@kyriacos/don-t-transfer-ethereum-from-binance-to-bitstamp) use newly generated deposit addresses (no smart contract)

**Bitstamp and Binance:**

> [Exchanges like Bitstamp and Binance](https://steemit.com/cryptocurrency/@kyriacos/don-t-transfer-ethereum-from-binance-to-bitstamp) have client smart contracts.
> In other words, the customer has a dedicated address to deposit all
> ERC-20 related tokens to it. This wallet though has to first go
> through a smart contract wallet that is owned from the exchange

**Bittrex:**

> [Warning - sending ETH to Bittrex](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/6ucbnl/warning_sending_eth_to_bittrex_is_a_smart/) is a smart contract invocation..
> So here's what I found after a friend asked for help.. When you ask
> for deposit address in Bittrex, what happens behind the scenes is that
> a new instance of smart contract is created just for you..

Why do some exchanges choose to generate a new deposit address for each customer while others choose to move it through a smart contract first? What are the benefits/drawbacks of each approach?